# adding ImageView to tableLayout programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a list of bitmap images, How can I add this bitmap to a tableLayout programmatically?

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
    TableLayout table = new TableLayout(this);
    for (int i = 0; i < mRows; i++) {

        TableRow tr = new TableRow(mContext);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        for (int j = 0; j < mCols; j++) {

            ImageView view = new ImageView(this);
            view.setImageResource(R.drawable.star_on)
            tr.addView(view);
        }
        table.addView(tr);
    }
```

This generates the whole table / grid programmatically. You can see how it instantiates an ImageView and sets the image.

Comment: how do you set imageviews width and height? I wanted to make them 32*32 but I could not. what's the way of doing it?